# Hidden inputs are missing from Request in Asp.net mvc3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, hidden-field

I'm using asp.net mvc3 ajax.beginform, and recently I've encountered a very strange problem.
It seems that some of the hidden input's I've placed inside the form do not exist in the request object.
I am not changing these values in any way after the post.
Any idea what is the reason?

Here's an example of a form that's giving me some trouble.

```
<form action="/PriceListItems/PriceUpdate" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" id="form0" method="post">

    <input id="item_Id" name="item.Id" type="hidden" value="3">
    <input id="price_TariffId" name="price.TariffId" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input class="input-mini" 
           data-val="true" 
           data-val-number="The field Price must be a number." 
           data-val-regex="incorrect number" 
           data-val-regex-pattern="(^N/A$)|(^[-]?(\d+)(\.\d{0,3})?$)|(^[-]?(\d{1,3},(\d{3},)*\d{3}(\.\d{1,3})?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3})?)$)" 
           data-val-required="שדה זה הינו חובה" 
           id="itemTariff_3_1" 
           name="price.Price" 
           onchange="postThis(this);" 
           type="text" 
           value="300.00"> 
    <span class="help-block">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" 
                  data-valmsg-for="itemTariff_3_1" 
                  data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </span>
</form>
```

Thanks!

**solved it, but it was quite a disappointing solution..:**
i've replaced every jquery related script in my site so that it'll arrive from a CDN rather from my local files, but in the original versions.
and that was it.
everything suddenly started to click together.
frustrating, but works.
thanks,

Nir

Comment: can you post examples of a) whats in your view file and b) what the browser renders ?

Comment: Have you used hidden inputs as `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.item.Id)`?

Comment: **@Ingo** - this is what the browser renders, it's copy&paste from the rendered html.
**@Karthik** - i've tried this, as well as just @Html.Hidden() and even plain old html <input/> tag, but none of them worked.
notice that what is getting rendered is a perfectly valid html (at least to my understanding), and that's exactly the source of the problem.
thanks!